# Why do I see the top screen before I nagivate to the initialRouteName in react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, mobile, react-navigation

I am using the authentication flow that react-navigation recommends but I've noticed an odd behavior.

```
function chooseStack() {
    if (!auth.isLoggedIn){
        return (
            <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}} initialRouteName="Login">
                <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={Login}/>
                <Stack.Screen name='Signup' component={Signup}/>
                <Stack.Screen name='Forgot-Password' component={ForgotPassword}/>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}} initialRouteName="Drawer">
                <Stack.Screen name={'Placeholder'} component={Placeholder}/>
                <Stack.Screen name={'Onboarding'} component={Onboarding}/>
                <Stack.Screen name='Drawer' component={DrawerMenu}/>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        )
    }
}

if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null;
}


return (
    <SafeAreaProvider style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
        <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
            {chooseStack()}
        </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
);
```

As you can see, when a user isn't logged in the user is shown the login screen. When a user logs in the state of `isLoggedIn` will flip to true and the stack navigator switches. In the logged in navigator I have the DrawerMenu as my initialRouteName. This component is a Drawer Nav in and of itself that has 3 separate screens. One of which is a home screen.

What I expected to happen was when a member logs in they get immediately sent to the Home screen nested inside the Drawer, but what I noticed happening was I'd momentarily see the Onboarding component.

I was able to hack around this by adding the placeholder above the Onboarding component which is nothing but an empty View, but what I'd really like is for the Drawer to be the first thing that gets show.

Does anyone know why this happens?